# Cannot debug this crash: CFRunloop_Is_Servicing_The_Main_Dispatch_Queue

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, crash

Xcode 12.3 | macOS 11 app | Swift 5.3

I'm receiving a crash log from my users that I cannot debug in Xcode. I've read that would be an Apple bug, but I want to know how to reproduce this in order to avoid the function that triggers the crash. This is the resume:

[image]

And this is the header of the crash file:

```
Process:               MyAppName [2201]
Path:                  /Applications/MyAppName.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppName
Identifier:            es.MyAppName.macos
Version:               4.1.0 (45310)
App Item ID:           1508553735
App External ID:       840077941
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MyAppName [2201]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-01-21 17:42:02.638 -0600
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4FAA8358-ABB0-CC49-10CE-A880D7BC8C04

Sleep/Wake UUID:       0017D1E7-8C98-4D2E-BD79-C5CFC91FE20F

Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       710 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019d0efcec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d120c24 pthread_kill + 292 (pthread.c:1388)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019d068864 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   es.MyAppName.macos              0x00000001055b3b84 0x104a84000 + 11729796
4   es.MyAppName.macos              0x00000001055b1690 0x104a84000 + 11720336
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d320654 __handleUncaughtException + 676 (NSException.m:253)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019cfca6bc _objc_terminate() + 132 (objc-exception.mm:700)
7   es.MyAppName.macos              0x000000010557d240 0x104a84000 + 11506240
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019d0e00e0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019d0e006c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cf74434 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:562)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cf81e1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 836 (inline_internal.h:2548)
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d25b9dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d21a868 __CFRunLoopRun + 2508 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d219730 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001a4d22f0c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292 (EventLoop.c:455)
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001a4d22d3c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 688 (EventBlocking.c:326)
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001a4d22a6c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76 (EventBlocking.c:170)
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000019f9eedb0 _DPSNextEvent + 868 (CGDPSReplacement.m:584)
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000019f9ed730 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1312 (appEventRouting.m:1377)
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000019f9df58c -[NSApplication run] + 600 (NSApplication.m:3278)
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000019f9b0d74 NSApplicationMain + 1064 (NSApplication.m:8773)
22  es.MyAppName.macos              0x0000000104f254f8 0x104a84000 + 4855032
23  es.MyAppName.macos              0x0000000104f254bc 0x104a84000 + 4854972
24  es.MyAppName.macos              0x0000000104a93548 0x104a84000 + 62792
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019d13cf54 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019d0e7ce8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019d0e8098 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   es.MyAppName.macos              0x00000001055aabe0 0x104a84000 + 11693024
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d12106c _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:881)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019d0e7ce8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019d0e8098 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d21be88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d21a35c __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d219730 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x000000019fb6f240 _NSEventThread + 216 (NSEvent.m:5211)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d12106c _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:881)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019d0e7ce8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019d0e8098 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d21be88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d21a35c __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000019d219730 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00000001a16c5930 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 572 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1374)
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000019df990f4 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d12106c _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:881)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bd8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bd8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bd8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bd8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bd8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019d11bd8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x000000013eb1a200   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x94cf92498d1f6560  x10: 0x0000000000003ffe  x11: 0x000000020863d50a
   x12: 0x000000020863d50a  x13: 0x000000000000001e  x14: 0x0000000000000881  x15: 0x000000008000001f
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000200736eb0  x18: 0x0000000130093940  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000105bd3d40  x21: 0x0000000000000303  x22: 0x0000000105bd3e20  x23: 0x000000013eb35800
   x24: 0x0000600001d74240  x25: 0x0000600001d74120  x26: 0x00000001f1065285  x27: 0x00000001f1066aeb
   x28: 0x000000019d61f90c   fp: 0x000000016b379cc0   lr: 0x000000019d120c24
    sp: 0x000000016b379ca0   pc: 0x000000019d0efcec cpsr: 0x40000000
   far: 0x0000600002564000  esr: 0x56000080
```